# How to solve this compatibility issue when exporting Simulink model with Simscape blocks from R2015b to R2015a

Tags: matlab, compatibility, simulink, simscape, simmechanics

I have a Simulink R2015b model containing SimElectronics and SimMechanics blocks. This model is functional. A colleague of mine asked to export the model to R2015a. However, when I execute this model, I obtain following error message:

> Component: Simulink | Category: Model error
>
> * ['model name']: Not enough input derivatives were provided for one or more Simulink-PS Converter blocks for the solver chosen. Implicit solvers (ode23t, ode15s, and ode14x) typically require fewer input derivatives than explicit solvers, and local solvers never require any. You can provide more input derivatives by selecting different options (turning input filtering on, for instance) on the Input Handling tab of Simulink-PS Converter blocks linked below: ...'model name/DC_motor/Simulink-PS Converter' (1 required, 0 provided)

What does it mean and what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time parameters are lost when exporting to an old version. I recommend to open both versions side-by-side and check the solver options and parameters of blocks which are relevant.

Comment: Which solver are you using for your R2105b model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that upon exporting my Simulink file from R2015b to R2015a, the solver was changed from 'variable time-step, auto' to 'variable time-step, ode45'. I manually chose another variable time-step solver, and I did not receive the error anymore.